# Transform python datetime.datetime

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

My Postgres database saves dates in that format here `2019-05-22 18:01:38.425533+00`. For my regression model, I must work with that date. Therefore I tried to transform it with `df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)`. Am I choosing the right format to process my data? If I plot my data it renders that image here. Data has values from 0 - 200 which doesn't seem right.

```
# Load data
def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('event_data.csv')
    df['created'] = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    return df

event_data = load_event_data()
print("The defined index is", event_data.index.name)

# Visualize data
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(event_data.index, event_data.tickets_sold_sum)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Rentals")
```

Here some sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJAcamytX4zmQBpbQZYIi-HK5T0JlAJ5Dx3b1D6adxQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Can you show the data what you are plotting? Can you give a sample please?

Comment: Sure here some sample data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJAcamytX4zmQBpbQZYIi-HK5T0JlAJ5Dx3b1D6adxQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You just need to set the index as created and you will get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is problem you plot index values instead column `created`, so use:

```
plt.plot(event_data.created, event_data.tickets_sold_sum)
```

Or use pandas for ploting:

```
event_data.plot(x='created', y='tickets_sold_sum')
```

If need wotking with `DatetimeIndex` first create it - e.g. by parameters `index_col` and `parse_dates`:

```
def load_event_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('created.csv', index_col='created',parse_dates=['created'])
    return df

event_data = load_event_data()
```

---

```
print (event_data.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-22 18:01:38.425533+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:02:17.867726+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:02:32.441820+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:03:07.093599+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:03:22.857492+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:04:07.453356+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:04:24.382271+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:04:34.670751+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:05:04.781586+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:05:28.475102+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:05:41.469483+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:04.184309+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:07.344332+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:21.596053+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:29.980078+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:36.331180+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:46.557717+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:06:50.681479+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:07:07.288164+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:07:12.296925+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:07:42.836565+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:07:56.903366+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:09:03.798696+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:09:20.485152+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:10:22.913068+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:10:30.922313+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:11:36.149465+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:11:45.239620+00:00',
               '2019-05-22 18:11:48.826544+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='created', freq=None)
```

---

```
print("The defined index is", event_data.index.name)

# Visualize data
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
plt.plot(event_data.index, event_data.tickets_sold_sum)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Rentals")
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, not sure if that's the problem. I define created as index. Wasn't clear when I posted it, but I added the beginning of my code now.

Comment: @JoeyCoder - Yes, it is problem - `index` is not Datetimeindex in your solution, need ploting column or create `DatetimeIndex`

Comment: Aha, that's what I was looking for, thank you. I think I still have to combine data for each day as I will have approx 90 days in my real data, but I will try that with the solution you gave me here! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have tried:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> df = pd.read_csv("d.csv")
>>> df
                          created  event_id  tickets_sold  tickets_sold_sum
0   2019-05-22 18:01:38.425533+00         1            90                90
1   2019-05-22 18:02:17.867726+00         1            40               130
2    2019-05-22 18:02:32.44182+00         1            13               143
3   2019-05-22 18:03:07.093599+00         1             0               143
4   2019-05-22 18:03:22.857492+00         1            10               153
5   2019-05-22 18:04:07.453356+00         1            14               167
6   2019-05-22 18:04:24.382271+00         1            14               181
7   2019-05-22 18:04:34.670751+00         1             7               188
8   2019-05-22 18:05:04.781586+00         1            10               198
9   2019-05-22 18:05:28.475102+00         1             2               200
10  2019-05-22 18:05:41.469483+00         1             0               200
11  2019-05-22 18:06:04.184309+00         1            19               219
12  2019-05-22 18:06:07.344332+00         1            18               237
13  2019-05-22 18:06:21.596053+00         1             9               246
14  2019-05-22 18:06:29.980078+00         1            20               266
15   2019-05-22 18:06:36.33118+00         1            11               277
16  2019-05-22 18:06:46.557717+00         1            15               292
17  2019-05-22 18:06:50.681479+00         1            10               302
18  2019-05-22 18:07:07.288164+00         1            17               319
19  2019-05-22 18:07:12.296925+00         1            11               330
20  2019-05-22 18:07:42.836565+00         1             5               335
21  2019-05-22 18:07:56.903366+00         1            17               352
22  2019-05-22 18:09:03.798696+00         1            13               365
23  2019-05-22 18:09:20.485152+00         1             9               374
24  2019-05-22 18:10:22.913068+00         1            14               388
25  2019-05-22 18:10:30.922313+00         1             9               397
26  2019-05-22 18:11:36.149465+00         1            12               409
27   2019-05-22 18:11:45.23962+00         1            13               422
28  2019-05-22 18:11:48.826544+00         1             4               426
>>> df.set_index("created",inplace=True)
>>> df
                               event_id  tickets_sold  tickets_sold_sum
created
2019-05-22 18:01:38.425533+00         1            90                90
2019-05-22 18:02:17.867726+00         1            40               130
2019-05-22 18:02:32.44182+00          1            13               143
2019-05-22 18:03:07.093599+00         1             0               143
2019-05-22 18:03:22.857492+00         1            10               153
2019-05-22 18:04:07.453356+00         1            14               167
2019-05-22 18:04:24.382271+00         1            14               181
2019-05-22 18:04:34.670751+00         1             7               188
2019-05-22 18:05:04.781586+00         1            10               198
2019-05-22 18:05:28.475102+00         1             2               200
2019-05-22 18:05:41.469483+00         1             0               200
2019-05-22 18:06:04.184309+00         1            19               219
2019-05-22 18:06:07.344332+00         1            18               237
2019-05-22 18:06:21.596053+00         1             9               246
2019-05-22 18:06:29.980078+00         1            20               266
2019-05-22 18:06:36.33118+00          1            11               277
2019-05-22 18:06:46.557717+00         1            15               292
2019-05-22 18:06:50.681479+00         1            10               302
2019-05-22 18:07:07.288164+00         1            17               319
2019-05-22 18:07:12.296925+00         1            11               330
2019-05-22 18:07:42.836565+00         1             5               335
2019-05-22 18:07:56.903366+00         1            17               352
2019-05-22 18:09:03.798696+00         1            13               365
2019-05-22 18:09:20.485152+00         1             9               374
2019-05-22 18:10:22.913068+00         1            14               388
2019-05-22 18:10:30.922313+00         1             9               397
2019-05-22 18:11:36.149465+00         1            12               409
2019-05-22 18:11:45.23962+00          1            13               422
2019-05-22 18:11:48.826544+00         1             4               426
>>> plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))
<Figure size 1500x600 with 0 Axes>
>>> plt.plot(df.index[:10], df.tickets_sold_sum[:10])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000022C7FBF5898>]
>>> plt.xlabel("Date")
Text(0.5,0,'Date')
>>> plt.ylabel("Rentals")
Text(0,0.5,'Rentals')
>>> plt.show()
```

I truncated the values to 10 as I was not able to show them distinctly. Here is the image:
[image: outpput images]

Answer (score 0):

Can you take data from Postgres `SELECT TO_CHAR(date, 'YYYYMMDD');` two times, one to train the model and other with desireD time format to plot it ?

Comment: I was more looking for a way to transform the data after I got the data export. Would make it easier long-term as that's how I will get the data in the future as well.